# iis process serving application pool exceeded time limits during shut down

Tags: asp.net, iis

Recently, some of my IIS application is having no response. I check the event log and found that some 
error happened in WAS service which cause some application pool to be stopped.

The following is the error message.
 I can see only the process id causing 
the problem.

I checked the error and find in one apppool a process is exceeded time limits during shut down.
Is that possible the process cannot shutdown and cause the other apppool to shutdown. My solutions is set the Test_pool application pool timeout to 1440 minutes(24 hour) and set recylcing time at a specific time
of the day to avoid the shutdown failure of process and prevent the auto shutdown of application pool. Is that workable?

```
A process serving application pool 'CEHL_POOL' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '529004'.

A worker process '504596' serving application pool 'TEST_POOL' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.

A worker process with process id of '794136' serving application pool 'TEST_POOL' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.

Application pool 'TEST_POOL' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
```

Comment: Only the last two are critical issues ("being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool."), and that's called rapid fail protection. You can learn more from https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/dec/19/iis-7-and-rapid-fail-protection However, troubleshooting the root cause can be tough, so you might open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event logs included mutiple errors with different application pool. So please point out which application pool stop responding. The error message "**exceeded time limits during shut down**" means the application failed to finish all current requests inside the process before application pool shutdown timeout reached. So either threads hang up or locked up.

“**being automatically disabled due to a series of failures。。。**”is caused by rapid failure protection, so you need to check application events and  you should be able to find the crash event.

No matter crash or hang,  you need to reproduce the issue and monitor the request status inside worker process monitor. It will show the time taken and current handler. You may need to collect and analyze dump file to trace the root cause.

Besides, in some case, http.sys will cause this issue because it is no longer able to wake up a new appliction pool. You may need to check whether your application pool is able to be waked up after your application stop responding.

Comment: Where can I find the application events?

Comment: Just event viewer->windows log->application. You should be able to find the event genereated by IIS or .net runtime.